# Is it possible to use multiple spaces in title?

Tags: filters, title

I would like to use three spaces as divider in my titles.
I remove all filters with:

```
remove_all_filters('the_title');
```

and add my own filter:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'my_title_filter');
```

for example my filter replaces 3 spaces with 3 dots, like:

```
$title = preg_replace('#(\s\s\s)#', '...', $title);
```

but, nothing works.

How can i avoid the replacement of multiple spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title), the filter actually has 2 arguments, which needs to be stated:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function ( $title, $id = null ) {
    return preg_replace('#(\s{3})#', '&hellip;', $title);
}, 10, 2 );
```

You could as well just use a placeholder that you replace on the fly – might be easier.

In case above does not work, you might want to give it try exactly before you call it:

```
$filters = $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['the_title'];

foreach ( $filters as $priority => $filter ) {
    remove_all_filters('the_title', $priority);
}

add_filter( 'the_title', function ( $title, $id = null ) {
    return preg_replace('#(\s{3})#', '&hellip;', $title);
}, 10, 2 );

the_title();
```

If ^ above works, then you have a problem with removing the filters properly. You might want to just `var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_filter']['the_title'];)` above the call for `the_title()` and then take a look of what was left in and care about that.

Comment: It is working fine, but the real issue is the QUICK-EDIT function. I'm edit the title with multiple spaces with the quick editor, then save/update the quick editor and reload it in the full editor ... the spaces are gone. When i edit the title in full editor and save and reload it then the blank spaces are still there.